# What is a Cawdle?

Tags: meaning, thomas-deloney, jack-of-newbury

At the end of the first chapter of Thomas Deloney's *Jack of Newbury*, Jack's unnamed wife makes him a "Cawdle":

> In the morning his wife rose betime, and merrily made him a Cawdle, and bringing it up to his bed side, asked him how he did?
>   
> (...)
>   And therefore forgiving each other all injuries past, having also tride one anothers patience, let us quench these burning coales of contention, with the sweete juyce of a faithfull kiss, and shaking hands, bequeath all our anger to the eating up of this Cawdle.

From the context, I assume a "cawdle" is some sort of dish. But what type of dish exactly?

When looking up "cawdle" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=cawdle&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1), I get the question, "Did you mean castle?" When looking up the term on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=cawdle&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1), it gives me search results for "candle".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A caudle (or caudel) was a hot drink that recurred in various guises throughout British cuisine from the Middle Ages into Victorian times. It was thick and sweet, and seen as particularly suitable and sustaining for invalids and new mothers. At some periods of history, caudle recipes were based on milk and eggs, like eggnog. Later variants were more similar to a gruel, a sort of drinkable oatmeal porridge. Like the original forms of posset (a drink of wine and milk, rather than a set dessert), a caudle was usually alcoholic.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caudle)

> A general term for thickened drinks. Typically wine, milk or ale thickened with flour, oatmeal or egg, sweetened and spiced.

[From foods of England](http://www.foodsofengland.co.uk/caudelorcaudle.htm)